# Download complete Phylogenetic Tree as JSON

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, taxonomy

I would like to integrate the phylogenetic tree into a website. Does anyone know where I can download the complete tree? Best would be a JSON, which looks something like this:

```json
[{
  "level": "domain",
  "name": "eukaryota",
  "commonNames": {
    "en": ["eukaryotes"],
    "de": ["Eukaryoten", "Eukaryonten"]
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "level": "kingdom",
      "name": "plantae",
      "commonNames": {
        "en": ["plants"],
        "de": ["Pflanzen"]
      },
      "children": [...]
    },
    {
      "level": "kingdom",
      "name": "animalia",
      "commonNames": {
        "en": ["animals"],
        "de": ["Tiere"]
      },
      "children": [...]
    },
    ...
  ]
},
{
  "level": "domain",
  "name": "bacteria",
  "commonNames": {
    "en": ["bacteria"],
    "de": ["Bakterien"]
  },
  "children": [...]
}]
```

Other formats and structures are ok, too. The important thing is that the level of the nodes can be retrieved. In the end I only want to have the main levels Domain, Kingdom, Phylum, Class, Order, Family, Genus and Species in the tree. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_(biology)#/media/File:Biological_classification_L_Pengo_vflip.svg) So if there are more nodes from other levels like Clade, Tribe or Subfamily, it must be possible to identify and remove them.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

NCBI maintains an SQL dump of their [taxonomic database](https://ncbiinsights.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2018/02/22/new-taxonomy-files-available-with-lineage-type-and-host-information/)

You can see what that contains [here](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/taxonomy/new_taxdump/taxdump_readme.txt)

For smaller requests (depending on what you need), you might also consider the ENSEMBL REST API - although I don't know of a way to retrieve the complete tree (shoot them an email): https://rest.ensembl.org/taxonomy/classification/53399?content-type=application/json

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth looking at the [Tree of Life](http://tolweb.org/tree/) web project, it isn't downloadable but its a reference source that can be improved on and updated in your website.

ToL contains trees linking everything from bacteria, archaea through to the complete diversity of eukaryotes, but its a bit old with 2008 from my taxonomic knowledge being the last update for some of the entries, e.g. Plasmodium spp..